# KiCAD Track Connection Fault

Tags: pcb, kicad, pad

I am designing a board on KiCAD and I am facing an unfamiliar issue. Most of the pad connection is done successfully but a few pads can't be connected. While I am starting a new track between pads, all it happens is that the arrow goes randomly and can't get close to the pad.

[image]

I also checked clearance settings, It set up to 0,1mm so it should be okay. what may cause the problem?

Comment: drop the tracksize to test, it looks like the track maybe too wide for the pad and thus falling fowl of another constraint

Comment: I tried that one too. I just figured out that components on the edge which are too close cant be connected. Components are desired to be far from edges I suppose.

Comment: A good way to check why the autorouter doesn't want to draw a trace is to switch it to "Highlight Collisions" mode and try to route the trace again. The things that light up are too close.